# Code running under ant doesn't find a properties file unless I fork the JVM

Tags: java, ant, properties-file

I'm just getting started with Ant, and I'm having problems getting a "run" target to work. Part of my code loads a properties file, and it always fails to find this file unless I make my run target use a new JVM. Below is a very simplified example, the "run" target fails, the "run_fork" target works. My understanding is that Ant has it's own class loader that replaces the default one, so I imagine this is mucking with the search path somehow. Is there any way I can change my code to make this work without having to fork a new JVM?

build.xml:

```
<project name="PropsExample" default="compile" basedir=".">

<property name="src" location="src"/>
<property name="bin" location="bin"/>

<target name="init">
    <tstamp/>
    <mkdir dir="${bin}"/>
</target>

<target name="compile" depends="init">
    <javac includeAntRuntime="false" srcdir="${src}" destdir="${bin}"/>
    <copy todir="${bin}">
        <fileset dir="${src}" includes="**/*.properties"/>
    </copy>
</target>

<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${bin}"/>
    <delete dir="${dist}"/>
</target>

<target name="run" depends="compile">
    <java classname="com.example.Test">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${bin}"/>
        </classpath>
    </java>
</target>

<target name="run_fork" depends="compile">
    <java fork="true" classname="com.example.Test">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${bin}"/>
        </classpath>
    </java>
</target>
```

example code:

```
package com.example;

import java.util.Properties;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class PropertiesLoader {

    public static String getProperty() throws Exception {

        InputStream in = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("com/example/test.properties");
        if ( in == null ) {
            throw new Exception("Cannot find test.properties");
        }
        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.load(in);
        in.close();
        return p.getProperty("test");
    }
}
```

and:

```
package com.example;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        try {
            System.out.println(PropertiesLoader.getProperty());
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Should add, this is with Java 1.6.0_22 and Ant 1.8.1

Answer (score 2):

ANT, having already launched by the time it reads the XML file containing your run's specified classpath, cannot actually reset the classpath of the running JVM.  Instead it attempts to append to it as it goes with chains of classloaders; however, your call to the class loader is likely grabbing the root classloader.  You might want to do something like this:

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("com/example/test.properties");
```

which would force the class to use the same classloader as it was loaded with.  This should (hopefully) jump into the ClassLoader chain at the right spot, as if it loaded the current class and the properties file is appropriately "moved" along with the current class, then the properties file should be accessible through the same class loader.

Note that there are a lot of good reasons to fork the JVM anyway.  The most important in my mind is to rid the entire JVM of ANT related classes.  You don't want to accidentally bind your run time to classes which are only available during the software build process, and if you want to bind your classes to ANT, it should be managed as a 3rd party library (so you can control the versions it binds to, the degree of binding, the ability to reproduce the build identically across multiple versions / releases of ANT, etc.)

Comment: sorry, removed the extra "class" which was unnecessary.

Comment: Don't you mean `getResourceAsStream` rather than `getSystemResourceAsStream`?

Comment: @Edwin Thanks, I was leaning towards always forking for exactly those reasons, it just seemed as though what I was doing ought to work. Another line I found that worked whether I forked or not was `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("com/example/test.properties");` but I don't entirely understand why this works as there's no threading going on (or is there?).

Comment: @Abayliss, when the JVM starts up it reads the CLASSPATH property variable and configures the main class loaders (there's 3 of them).  Then it loads the classes for ANT, and starts processing ANT's code, which then reads the build.xml file.  Inside the build.xml file, ANT determines it needs to run something via the java command, so it loads the needed class.  But wait!  That class is not on the classpath, so ANT uses it's own classloader (which it can create / destroy on command) to load the class.  Asking the system class loader won't use the "right" classloader for the ant configured path.

Comment: @Abayliss, So, telling the object to use the same class loader that it was loaded with to load the properties file is the correct way to load a properties file.  If you get loaded in a different manner (like within ant or tomcat or an EJB container, etc) you can't be certain that the system class loader knows anything about the loaded class (or it's associated properties files).  The reason it works on forking 100% is because ANT tells the forked JVM at startup, so the system class loader is configured with the bin path in place.